# Password protected excel using NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, passwords, npoi

i have a .net c# application in which im downloading one excel file on button click.
the code im using is

```
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.HSSF.Util;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
```

then some codes.

```
HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = book.CreateSheet("StatusReport");
```

some code for formatting the excel,then some code for downloading the excel.

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-16";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "MpiDischargeReport.xls"));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            book.Write(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

this will help me to download the excel,but i need to make that excel as a password protected one.
please help.

Answer (score 3):

This  is not working in 1.2.5 may work in 2.0
Try

```
var sheet = book.CreateSheet("StatusReport");
            sheet.ProtectSheet("Password");
```

Answer (score 1):

NPOI is a .net clone of the POI-Java-Libary. So I looked at the POI-Documentation for the class "HSSFWorkbook":

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html

As you can see there is a method called "writeProtectWorkbook" that you can use to password protect the workbook.


Also take a look at the documentation for the class "HSSFSheet": 
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html

As you can see there is a method called "protectSheet" that you can use to password protect the sheet.


I never tried it out . But may it help?

Comment: ok.
i will try it,and let u know..
thanks for ur valuable time and effort.

Comment: i tried it out too. seems to just protect the workbook/worksheet from modifications. but the users will still be able to open it and read it without entering a password.