# How to open an excel file with write protection using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to automate a process, for this process I need to open an Excel file that is both Write Protected and Password Protected. 
When you try to open a file manually it ask for "Password to Open" and "Password to Modify" could you please let me know how to open that type of file using C#?

Comment: have alook at NPOI and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786649/password-protected-excel-using-npoi

Comment: Sorry, seems like neither NPOI nor closedXML are able to do the job, as they both use the openXML specs. Your best bet might be to use interop (search for "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"),

Comment: EEPlus could do it: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample10.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the password for that xls file then you may install this Spire.XLS for .NET.
It’s an excel component to decrypt xls files using c#.
Here’s a sample code below:

[C#]:

```cs
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

workbook.LoadFromFile("test.xls");

Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

sheet.Unprotect( "password" );

workbook.SaveToFile("result.xls",ExcelVersion.Version97to2003)
```

I hope this helps.

Reference:
https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Decrypt-Excel-Worksheet-in-C-VB.NET.html

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two approaches to handle Excel (and Office files in general) programatically, esp. in C#:

- InterOp
- third-party libraries

With interop you are using an excel version that is installed on the machine, with libraries there is usually no need for an excel installation.

Most libraries like NPOI and closedXML can handle the "no modification" part, but they lack the ability to encrypt (password-protect) a file.
This is also heavily depended on which exact version you use (preferably the most recent one).

There is a code example for EPPlus, which looks like encrypting a file (`EncryptionAlgorithm.AES192`) might be working.